# Function with radicals

Tags: functions

If: $$f \left(\sqrt {4x}+6\over {3}\right)=\frac{x-9}{36}$$Then $$f(4\sqrt x)=?$$

I don't know how to use the first equality and then go for the second. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: you are given that $\,f\big(g(x)\big)=h(x)\,$, then $f(x)=h\big(g^{-1}(x)\big)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{4x}}{3} + 2 = 4\sqrt{t}.
$$
Then it can be checked that
$$
x = 9(2\sqrt{t}-1)^2.
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(4\sqrt{t}) = f(\frac{\sqrt{4x}}{3} + 2) = \frac{x-9}{36}
=  \frac{(2\sqrt{t}-1)^2-1}{4}.
$$